# withDefault can not find the class

Tags: groovy

Having:

```
class Task {
    Integer code
    String name
}

def classDefinition = """
            package untitled24

            class TasksCommand {
                List tasks = [].withDefault { new Task() }
            }
            TasksCommand
        """

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader)
Class<?> definedClass = shell.evaluate(classDefinition)
```

Execution result is:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Task 
 @ line 5, column 47.
   List tasks = [].withDefault { new Task()
                             ^
```

Any idea? (groovy version is 1.8.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your Task definition is not in a package, so the code inside `untitled24` cannot locate the class...

If you change the above to:

```
package woo

class Task {
  Integer code
  String name
}

def classDefinition = """package untitled24
                        |
                        |class TasksCommand {
                        |  List tasks = [].withDefault { new woo.Task() }
                        |}
                        |TasksCommand""".stripMargin()

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader)
Class<?> definedClass = shell.evaluate(classDefinition)
```

it should work... (added `stripMargin` for readbility)